# Database DB2 Triggers

Tags: database, stored-procedures, triggers, db2, database-trigger

I am writing some triggers for our DB2 database tables, but I don't have rights to test them...I know...but just a quick question here.  Does the NEW and OLD keywords give you the whole row that was updated or just the certain fields that were updated?  For example, if I have a table where 1 row just got updated and, only 2 fields in that row got updated/changed do I still get the whole row to work with when I use the NEW keyword?  That was my understanding, that even though other fields got updated and others didn't,  that I could still refer to any field/value of the entire row using the NEW keyword.

Some illustration here:

Table row:

```
|first_name | last_name | age | gender | state        | city        |

|"Tom"      | "Sawyer"  | 80  | "male" | "California" | "Sacramento"|
```

Update to same table row:

```
|first_name | last_name | age | gender | state        | city        |

|"John"     | "Doe"     | 80  | "male" | "California" | "Sacramento"|
```

After the update do I still get the age, gender, state, and city field values using the NEW keyword?  As in NEW.age = 80, NEW.state = "California" etc.

or does it only give me the first and last name because they were the only fields to change?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access all the columns in the row with the `NEW` correlation.